# ¿Como vincular la información de variables a un evento click al presionar un marker?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Estoy trabajando con Leaflet y necesito agregar un evento click a los iconos del mapa para que la información asociada a cada uno se muestre en la card del costado en el formulario de información en lugar de abrirse en un popup. Estuve tratando con diversas formas pero no logro que me tome el evento click al presionar uno de los markers, solo necesito que al presionar un marcador este dé un mensaje con "console.log" para saber si me esta tomando el evento click.

```
//variables
let puntosReciclaje = [
{
  'id': 01,
  'direccion': "calle tanto",
  'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
},
{
  'id': 02,
  'direccion': "calle tanto",
  'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
},
{
  'id': 03,
  'direccion': "calle tanto",
  'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
},
{
  'id': 04,
  'direccion': "calle tanto",
  'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
},
{
  'id': 05,
  'direccion': "calle tanto",
  'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
},
{
  'id': 06,
  'direccion': "calle tanto",
  'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
},
{
  'id': 07,
  'direccion': "calle tanto",
  'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
},
{
  'id': 08,
  'direccion': "calle tanto",
  'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
},
{
  'id': 09,
  'direccion': "calle tanto",
  'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
},
{
  'id': 10,
  'direccion': "calle tanto",
  'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
}];
let campanasVidrio = [
  {
    'id': 01,
    'direccion': "calle tanto",
    'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
  },
  {
    'id': 02,
    'direccion': "calle tanto",
    'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
  },
];
let jaulasPET = [
  {
    'id': 01,
    'direccion': "calle tanto",
    'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
  },
  {
    'id': 02,
    'direccion': "calle tanto",
    'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
  },
  {
    'id': 03,
    'direccion': "calle tanto",
    'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
  },
  {
    'id': 04,
    'direccion': "calle tanto",
    'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
  }
];
let puntosAceite = [
  {
    'id': 01,
    'direccion': "calle tanto",
    'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
  },
  {
    'id': 02,
    'direccion': "calle tanto",
    'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
  },
  {
    'id': 03,
    'direccion': "calle tanto",
    'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
  }
];
let puntosPilas = [
{
  'id': 01,
  'direccion': "calle tanto",
  'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
},
{
  'id': 02,
  'direccion': "calle tanto",
  'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
},
{
  'id': 03,
  'direccion': "calle tanto",
  'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
},
{
  'id': 04,
  'direccion': "calle tanto",
  'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
},
{
  'id': 05,
  'direccion': "calle tanto",
  'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
},
{
  'id': 06,
  'direccion': "calle tanto",
  'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
},
{
  'id': 07,
  'direccion': "calle tanto",
  'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
},
{
  'id': 08,
  'direccion': "calle tanto",
  'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"
}
];


//colocar los marcadores
//Puntos de reciclaje General
puntosReciclaje = L.layerGroup([
  L.marker([-36.79157, -73.08062], {
    icon: verde
  }),
  L.marker([-36.78241, -73.10576], {
    icon: verde
  }),
  L.marker([-36.78477, -73.1156], {
    icon: verde
  }),
  L.marker([-36.79504, -73.11584], {
    icon: verde
  }),
  L.marker([-36.79123, -73.0924], {
    icon: verde
  }),
  L.marker([-36.79005, -73.11393], {
    icon: verde
  }),
  L.marker([-36.79369, -73.11536], {
    icon: verde
  }),
  L.marker([-36.79713, -73.08733], {
    icon: verde
  }),
  L.marker([-36.80653, -73.08935], {
    icon: verde
  }),
  L.marker([-36.79744, -73.11513], {
    icon: verde
  }),
]);
//Puntos de campanas de vidrio
campanasVidrio = L.layerGroup([
  L.marker([-36.8011958427, -73.0928327219], {
    icon: morado
  }),
  L.marker([-36.7821537729, -73.1054401636], {
    icon: morado
  })
]);
//puntos de Jaulas PET
jaulasPET = L.layerGroup([
  L.marker([-36.79562, -73.08199], {
    icon: azul
  }),
  L.marker([-36.79205, -73.11484], {
    icon: azul
  }),
  L.marker([-36.78242, -73.10638], {
    icon: azul
  }),
  L.marker([-36.76692, -73.17136], {
    icon: azul
  })
]);
//Puntos de Recoleccion de Aceite
puntosAceite = L.layerGroup([
  L.marker([-36.79, -73.1139], {
    icon: naranjo
  }),
  L.marker([-36.78244, -73.10631], {
    icon: naranjo
  }),
  L.marker([-36.79163, -73.08058], {
    icon: naranjo
  })
]);
//Puntos de recoleccion de Pilas
puntosPilas = L.layerGroup([
  L.marker([-36.7916, -73.08056], {
    icon: rojo
  }),
  L.marker([-36.79708, -73.08723], {
    icon: rojo
  }),
  L.marker([-36.79008, -73.11395], {
    icon: rojo
  }),
  L.marker([-36.79552, -73.1142], {
    icon: rojo
  }),
  L.marker([-36.78457, -73.11574], {
    icon: rojo
  }),
  L.marker([-36.80149, -73.09492], {
    icon: rojo
  }),
  L.marker([-36.79221, -73.09936], {
    icon: rojo
  }),
  L.marker([-36.78259, -73.10631], {
    icon: rojo
  })
]);
```

estuve pensando que quizá las variables con los puntos en el mapa no están vinculados correctamente, de no ser así agradecería mucho que alguien con mas experiencia me oriente en cuanto a la lógica, intente con puntosReciclaje."id".on(click, function) o con solo puntosReciclaje.on(click, function) poniendo dentro un if con cada id e información correspondiente pero no logro vincularlos de ninguna manera para que al presionar un marcador este muestre la informacion en consola

Comment: Lo que primeramente no estoy entendiendo es por qué estás reasignando tus variables de un array de objetos con id, dirección y horario a un layerGroup.

Comment: @padaleiana es que en la primera parte tengo los datos de las variables en array con sus correspondientes datos, y el layergroup es para ubicar los marcadores en el mapa, esta mal así? y porque lo esta? si me pudieras explicar la teoría estaría agradecido

Comment: Estás sobreescribiendo las variables... Ej.: si tenés una variable que se llama _vari_, y _vari_ inicialmente vale 5 (`vari = 5`), si luego hacés `vari = 7` ahora _vari_ vale 7, no 5.

Comment: OH, ya veo disculpa, no note que las estaba sobre escribiendo, y si las pusiera solo en una algo como de esta manera? `let puntosReciclaje = L.layerGroup([L.marker([-36.79157, -73.08062], {icon: verde}, {'id':01,'direccion': "calle tanto",'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"})` de esta manera si guardaría la información? o `let puntosReciclaje = L.layerGroup([L.marker([-36.79157, -73.08062], {icon: verde}, {'id':01},{'direccion': "calle tanto"},{'horario': "10:00hrs-22:00hrs"})`

Comment: Lo segundo mucho sentido no tiene, porque estás queriendo agregar 3 objetos al marcador. Lo que probablemente estás queriendo agregar es un GeoJSON personalizado. Lo que encontré más rápidamente es [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736345/adding-properties-to-a-leaflet-layer-that-will-become-geojson-options). Y por cierto, _la documentación es tu amiga, **usala**_. No pruebes código solo porque sí, ni lo _adivines_.

Comment: vale, disculpa las molestias, es que los foros y cosas que busco las suelo buscar en español y no hay tanta documentación como en ingles, no se me da muy bien, gracias por la ayuda!!!

Comment: No es molestia. Centrate en aprender a preguntar/buscar, luego encontrarás la información más rápidamente. No olvides responder a tu pregunta en caso de que encuentres información que responda a la misma.